# Is it possible to change a model's parametrization when running a script?

Tags: modelica, dymola

For example:
in my script I launch a simulation of a model that have, among other things, 10 water volumes and  then store all the results in a specified .mat file.
With the final values of certain variables I would like to parametrize the same 10 volumes in another model, all in the same script.
I'm not quite skilled with Modelica languange (yet) but I firmly think that this is possible without the tediousness of doing it by hand.
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, then update your answer.

Comment: Yes, that is possible! Modelica parameters can be changed between simulations. From your description, I think the best way forward is to compile to FMU, then use a python script to run the simulation, read simulation results, set parameters, simulate again. There are several related answers already on SO, search for pyfmi examples or fmpy examples, and for DyMat examples.

Comment: @ Priyanka Thank you!